# JQuery .val() undefined(?) value on input

Tags: jquery

I've got a little problem with JQuery .val() used on an id of an input. I've tried many fruitless things so here I am.

I just try to get the value of the email input (what the user typed in before submition) when the user submits the form, but all I have is an empty line in the console (not even undefined value ?)

EDIT : It appears to work here, so my question is now why does this code not work ? Maybe my JQuery version is to old ?

Here is a simple version of my code, the script is at the end of the page (page system of JQuery mobile) so after the html of the concerned page.

```js
$('#loginForm').submit(function() {

  var email = $("#email").val();
  console.log(email);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#test" id="loginForm">

  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Pwd" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />

</form>
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Where is the above script in the below code in your original HTML? JQuery has to be included above all scripts that use JQuery.

Comment: `.val()` has been included in jQuery since version 1.0. Maybe you have another `#email` element on the page that is higher up in the DOM that is being selected? This can happen somewhat easily with jQuery Mobile sites.

Comment: And have you used `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers.

Yes I've included JQuery above all scripts. No I just have one #email. Yes I've tried with $(document).ready

Comment: I forgot to say that since #email is my first input, the code works when I write $('input').val() but I'ld like to know why it doesn't work with #email if it works with input.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. As strange as it may seem, the id name was the problem. I changed #email to #someswearword and it worked.

Thanks for your time, bye

Answer (score 0):

It seems form submited when user clicks "submit" button, page changes and console gets cleaned. So you can't see value. You can alert it instead of logging to console to be sure.

Comment: I suspect logging is not his real goal, but just using the value in the submit function.

Comment: yes console.log is working, but after submit page changes... so user4820423 can't see it on console.

Comment: Yes Barmar, logging is not my initial goal, it is just to 'debug' and see why my code doesn't work. I use the email (and password) for an authentication using btoa.

Comment: I've also tried to alert in vain. I've got an empty alert